# Full coverage background image on quarto title slide with a row of icons along the bottom

Tags: css, rstudio, quarto, reveal.js

I am trying to make a title slide for a reavaljs presentation using Rstudio and quarto. I would like my title slide to have full coverage background image and one or more small icons along the bottom (but not on other slides). I have attempted to modify [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74574308/multiple-images-logo-and-a-background-image-in-xaringan-title-slide) suggested for xaringan, but have not had any success. Here is my .qmd YAML and css:

```
---
title: "Test Presentation"
author: "Name"
format: 
  revealjs:
    embed-resources: true
    css: css/slides.css
editor: source
---
```

slides.css

```css
.title-slide {
  background-image: url(https://placeholder.pics/svg/100),
                    url(https://picsum.photos/id/870/800/600?grayscale);
  background-position: 2% 98%, center;
  background-size: 100px, cover;
}
```

I have also tried altering the title-slide-attributes to provide multiple images, but could not find a syntax that worked.

Based on the response by @shafee below, I tried:

```
---
title: "Test Presentation"
author: "Name"
format: 
  revealjs:
    theme: night
    embed-resources: true
    title-slide-attributes: 
      data-background-image: "https://placeholder.pics/svg/100,https://picsum.photos/id/870/800/600?grayscale"
      data-background-size: 100px, cover
      data-background-position: 2% 98%, center
editor: source
---
```

The issue is that when I pull revaljs out on its own line so that I can include other details such as embed-resources, only the icon shows up on the title slide. If I reverse the order of these, the background image shows up (in color instead of grayscale) but the icon is not present. The same behavior happens regardless of whether the title-slide-attributes block is indented or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same for Quarto revealjs too using [`title-slide-attributes`](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#main-title-slide-background).

Just pass the image path in a string (comma separated).

```
---
title: "Test Presentation"
author: "Name"
format: revealjs
title-slide-attributes: 
  data-background-image: "https://placeholder.pics/svg/100,https://picsum.photos/id/870/800/600?grayscale"
  data-background-size: 100px, cover
  data-background-position: 2% 98%, center
  
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation.

## Bullets

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code
```

[image: title slide background]

Comment: This works as you have posted, but when I pull the revealjs out in its own line to specify general slide behavior, it does not use the background image (but the icon does show up). I updated the original post to reflect this.

Comment: try indenting the whole `title-slide-attributes` to align along `embed-resources` .

Comment: It still does not work. It seems that the second (or more) image is not respected by title-slide-attributes when in this format. Only the first image listed shows up (I also tried putting the background first, and it shows up in color instead of grayscale, and the icon does not display)

Comment: @midden, Okay I am actually away from my laptop, so could not test for possible issues! But my guess is this has to be something with `embed-resources`. I am quite sure of that (since you have said the image shows in color). I would suggest try with local images (or you can download the images used in this question then use local filepath)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! This was the problem. I have added an updated answer to help folks who are struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @shafee, this has been solved. Apparently `embed-resources` is not compatible with a complex title slide. This is too bad, because I cannot usually provide a folder to a conference—they want a single file for me to present from and to share. I am not sure this is a bug, but it is certainly a design feature for the quarto/posit developers to consider.

In the short-term, however, this is GREAT. Thanks for your help!

```
---
title: "Test Presentation"
author: "Name"
format: 
  revealjs:
    theme: night
    scrollable: true
    echo: true
    incremental: false 
    code-fold: true
    code-overflow: scroll
    embed-resources: false
    title-slide-attributes: 
      data-background-image: "https://placeholder.pics/svg/100, https://placeholder.pics/svg/100,https://placeholder.pics/svg/100, https://picsum.photos/id/870/800/600?grayscale"
      data-background-size: 100px, 100px, 100px, cover
      data-background-position: "2% 98%, 50% 98%, 98% 98%, center"
editor: source
---
```

This yields:
[image]